# npm test task with mocha keeps on running

Tags: npm, mocha.js, npm-run

I have the following `test` task in npm:

```
"test": "env TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\"module\": \"commonjs\" }' mocha -r ts-node/register 'test/**/*.ts'",
```

When I run `npm run test` it performs tests but after running all of them the command does not finish.

Is there a way to alter the command in a way it will finish after all the tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding `--exit` flag for mocha